# Power BI - Comparing data at Row Level and concatenating the respective data in other column for same records

Tags: powerbi

I want to show the consolidated data for similar record in separate column in power bi data.

I have a data with two columns and i want the result like below in third & fourth column

3rd column result nothing but comparing unique id in rows, e.g. 1=2 =false, 2=2=true
4th column result nothing but concatenation of Value column for unique record

could you please help to achieve this in power bi - i want to create custom columns for these two result in data table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use CalculatedColumn in DAX:

```
Result = 

    CALCULATE(
        CONCATENATEX (
            CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES('Unique'[Value] ) ),
            'Unique'[Value],
            ", ",     
            'Unique'[Value],   
            ASC            
        ), ALL('Unique'[Value])
    )
```

And you Validation may be a measure:

```
Valid = if(SELECTEDVALUE('Unique'[Value]) = CALCULATE( max('Unique'[Value]), ALL('Unique'[Value])), FALSE(), TRUE())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi msta42a - thanks for quick response. outcome i am seeing in the table what i want but  i am not understanding the dax you used as i am not seeing ID field you used. i tried with  multiple options at my end but did not get success

Comment: In code, we don't need to use ID (because of CALCULATE -> engine know that we have ID in scope on the row).  What we need to do is to remove the context filter from value -> ALL('Unique'[Value]) does this.

Comment: Thank you, i used your logic and modified a bit and got the expected result. see below modified code
Result = 

    CALCULATE(
        CONCATENATEX (
            CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES('Unique'[Value] ) ),
            'Unique'[Value],
            ", ",     
            'Unique'[Value],   
            ASC            
        ), ALLexcept('unique', 'Unique'[ID])
    )